# Zend framework2 multi controller in module

Tags: zend-framework2

I've got a problem with adding many controllers in the one module. Zend2 is difficult for beginners.

I've created Module "Home" with Controllers "Home" and "News". HomeController is going fine but when I'm trying to connect to the NewsController I'm getting Fatal error: Class 'Home\Controller\NewsController' not found in C:\wamp\www\zend2\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager.php on line 170. And I don't know where the problem is.

My module.config looks like

```
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Home\Controller\Home' => 'Home\Controller\HomeController',
            'Home\Controller\News' => 'Home\Controller\NewsController',
        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/home[/][:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Home\Controller\Home',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'news' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/news[/][:action]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Home\Controller\News',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),

        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

I'm using navigation factory so navigation file looks like :

```
return array(
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Home',
                'route' => 'home'
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'News',
                'route' => 'news'
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
                'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory'
        )
    )
);
```

And Module.php looks like

```
namespace Home;

class Module {

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
                'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                        __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
                ),
                'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                        'namespaces' => array(
                                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                        ),
                ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

}
```

And NewsController looks like

```
namespace News\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class NewsController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

Comment: you haven't any controller part in your router config. try this for add controller part `'route' => '/news[/][:controller][/][:action]'`

Comment: This is not necessary, URLs don't need to include the controller name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller class you're declaring the namespace as:

```
namespace News\Controller;
```

yet in your module config you list the invokable class as `Home\Controller\NewsController`. The namespaces need to match, so you probably want to change the controller class namespace to:

```
namespace Home\Controller;
```